# Opening a jQuery popup instead of the default edit page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link which goes to the default edit page.
http://127.0.0.1:3000/calendars/16/edit
I want to invoke a jQuery popup to handle the edit action. I want the popup to have the editable section. 
Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Probably. But without posting something we can *see* (we can't access *your* localhost) it might be tricky to answer. Do you want to embed the *whole page* in the jQuery modal/popup?

Comment: @David - Yes, all the input fields needs to go inside the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straight forward just make a ajax call to the url (the one you have given above) on click of that link.
put the returned data in a DIV (say #xyz)
use jQuery Dialog (ref. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

```
$("#xyz").dialog();
$("#xyz form").submit(function(){
  // Do ajax call here to submit the form
  $("#xyz").dialog('close');
  return false;
})
```

Comment: I did not understand this part "just make a ajax call to the url (the one you have given above) on click of that link. put the returned data in a DIV (say #xyz)" - my edit form is edit.html.erb now do I put that returning content into a div ?